# How do I use cin to read an input with spaces until a tab is reached?

Tags: c++, input, cin

For instance, it will take "Jane Jam Doe    16" and read it as "Jane Jam Doe."

I've heard of the get line method but getting the entire line is not what I intend to do.

Comment: And what else did you researched? Because if this is everything, then you researched very badly.

Comment: You should also [read](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) about `getline`. It has a flexible view of what a "line" is.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't actually to hard to complete. I would recommend reading up on stringstreams. They are very useful with formating string data.

here is some pseudo code to get you started.

```
stringstream stream(string_to_read);
while(you_want_pieces)
    stream >> new_string;
```